# Android room select distinct table.calender from table

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

The problem faced is to get calendar field from table.

My actual Data class is:

```
@TypeConverters(CalendarConverters::class)
@Entity(tableName = MY_TABLE)
data class MyEpg(
    val updatedAt: Calendar,
    val epgName: String,
    val epgStartTime: Calendar,
    val epgEndTime: Calendar,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "calendar")
    val calendar: Calendar,
    val chName: String
) {
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Long = 0
}
```

I've used typeconverter as:

```
object CalendarConverters {
    @TypeConverter
    @JvmStatic
    fun fromTimestamp(value: Long?): Calendar? = value?.let { value ->
        GregorianCalendar().also { calendar ->
            calendar.timeInMillis = value
        }
    }

    @TypeConverter
    @JvmStatic
    fun toTimestamp(timestamp: Calendar?): Long? = timestamp?.timeInMillis
}
```

The query I used is:

```
 @Query("select distinct ${MY_TABLE}.calendar from $MY_TABLE order by ${MY_TABLE}.calendar asc")
 suspend fun getCalendars(): List<Calendar>
```

Error Shown in build view is

> The query returns some columns [calendar] which are not used by
>   java.lang.Object. You can use @ColumnInfo annotation on the fields to
>   specify the mapping.  You can suppress this warning by annotating the
>   method with @SuppressWarnings(RoomWarnings.CURSOR_MISMATCH). Columns
>   returned by the query: calendar. Fields in java.lang.Object: .
>           public abstract java.lang.Object getCalendars(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
>
> error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type
>   (java.lang.Object).
>           public abstract java.lang.Object getCalendars(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()

Note:
I've noticed that type converter to convert to long is being used while converting from long to date is not being used.

There is no any problem on getting any single fields or the complete object except for the single calendar item.

Comment: Can you show us your entity class code?
I suppose that you only need to define your column name by adding @ColumnInfo(name = "your name")

Comment: added data-class, I've used the columnInfo as well

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced your code but I'm not getting that error. However, I have some observations for you:

1. I noticed that as table name you use MY_TABLE but in the query you use My_TABLE with "lowercase y". Is this a typo?
2. You can avoid the use of @JvmStatic by replacing your object CalendarConverters to simple class. Object works with singleton pattern.
3. I'm supposing that the cause could be that you have invalid data inserted in the table MyEpg table, so then, when you do a request using your query, the column calendar contains a null value. That's could be the reason why you receive the next:

```
error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type (java.lang.Object). public abstract java.lang.Object getCalendars(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
```

You could solve the problem by adding a nullable indicator to the return type:

```
@Query("select distinct ${MY_TABLE}.calendar from $MY_TABLE order by ${MY_TABLE}.calendar asc")
 suspend fun getCalendars(): List<Calendar?>
```

Comment: no I've changed them in the question, they are different in project-implementation. Let me try with nullable

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you've forgotten to apply your TypeConverter (or have chosen wrong place to put the annotation)? There are two ways to do that in your case:

1. Apply it on Database-level:

`@Database(entities = arrayOf(YourEntity::class), version = 1)
 @TypeConverters(CalendarConverters::class)
 abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
 ...................`

2. Apply it on Entity level:

`@Entity(tableName = "your_table")
 @TypeConverters(CalendarConverters::class)
 data class YourEntity (`

and Dao level:

`@TypeConverters(CalendarConverters::class)
 suspend fun getCalendars():  List<Calendar>`

Comment: I've tried keeping on all places,
But noticed that type converter to convert to long is being used while converting from long to date is not being used.

Comment: It's strange. I tried your case and both described variants worked well without any error message